# Implicit function theorem problem from Munkres Analysis on Manifolds text

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

For the problem below, which is from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds section on the implicit function theorem, I'm getting the following solution $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \neq \frac{18}{5}$, but I saw a solution giving the answer as $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \neq \frac{2}{5}$

**My attempt:**

I began by checking the conditions for both $G$, and $H$, where $det\big(\frac{\partial G(2,-1,1)}{\partial y} \big) \neq 0$ and the same for $H$

(1) $\det \big(\frac{\partial H(2,-1,1)}{\partial y} \big)=2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+9+3\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$

(2) $\det \big(\frac{\partial G(2,-1,1)}{\partial y} \big)=f'(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$

and substituting (1) into (2) gives

$f'(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{18}{5}$

My thinking is that I was supposed to do something more with $f'(x,y)$ so that I could isolate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$?

Thanks

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to look at the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix $\dfrac{\partial(G,H)}{\partial(x,u)}$ and see that *it* is nonzero.

Comment: So I computed $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}=f'(x,y) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$;   $\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}=2u$;   $\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=u$;   $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u}=u+3u^2$.  I plugged $u=1$, in and computed the determinant and got, $f'(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: You should not be writing $f'(x,y)$. In particular, $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Moreover, $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u} = x + 3u^2$. Now fix it :)

Comment: I made a mistake in the comment I just deleted.  Could you still explain to me why we needed to check that the determinant of the $2x2$ matrix is non-zero. Wouldn't we just have to check that each of the partial derivatives from my first comment above are non-zero?  Thanks

Comment: You need to study the statement of the Implicit Function Theorem! There are never separate partial derivatives to check — always the non-vanishing of a $k\times k$ determinant if you're solving for (those) $k$ variables as functions of the remaining variables.

Comment: Am I correct in seeing this problem as a map from $P:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2}$, where $p(x,y,u)$ and the codomain are the $2$ functions $G$ and $H$.  Then we write $x$ and $u$ as functions of $y$, and apply the implicit function theorem to $P$, and hence we have to check that the determinant of the matrix you described in your answer is non-zero?

Comment: Yes, you're considering the map $P(x,y,u) = (G(x,y,u),H(x,y,u))$ and you want to know what will guarantee that the equation $P(x,y,u)=(0,0)$ allows you to solve for $x$ and $u$ as functions of $y$ near the point $(x,y,u)=(2,-1,1)$.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  I always appreciate your feedback and your online video lectures are also very helpful!

Comment: @TedShifrin Your Online videos are great service to humanity. Thank you very much for the above answer as well.